# checking dataframe columns (row by row) for multiple conditions in if

Tags: pandas, if-statement, dataframe, multiple-conditions

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,5,9],[2,1,5],[9,2,8]], index = [1,2,3], columns = ['A','B','C', 'D'])
```

Let's say I have a dataframe like df.
I want to compare all rows in df for 
if df['A']>df['B'] and df['B']< df['C'] and df['B']>df['D'], 
then if true df['E'] = 'yes' or 'no' for false. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe is not reproducible so do check for the error. I created a somewhat similar dataframe here.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,10], 'B': [1,5,5], 'C': [2,1,7], 'D': [9,2,4]})
```

You can add column E like this:

```
df['E'] = (df['A']>df['B']) & (df['B']< df['C']) & (df['B']>df['D'])
```

It gives desired output.

Comment: Thank you @Vaishali for the answer. For my case I need to do this with a if statement (for more analysis). When I tried this    ---import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,10], 'B': [1,5,5], 'C': [2,1,7], 'D': [9,2,4]})

if (df['A']>df['B']) & (df['B']< df['C']) & (df['B']>df['D']):
   df['E'] = 'yes'--- it gives me ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Any suggestions?

Comment: The solution is a conditional statement without using if. The value error you are getting is because df['E'] is a pandas Series and you can not assign a value to series like that

Comment: If you have to use if statement explicitly, here is the solution though i would not recommend it:E = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    if ((df['A'][i]>df['B'][i]) & (df['B'][i]< df['C'][i]) & (df['B'][i]>df['D'][i])):
        E.append('Yes')
    else:
        E.append('No')

Comment: Thanks  a lot, that makes sense!